# Android post picture to Facebook public page wall

Tags: android, facebook, image-uploading, facebook-comments, facebook-android-sdk

I'm currently able to post to a public page wall using:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("message", "I'm on your wall");



Request req = Request.newPostRequest(getSession(), "PowerCardSoftware/feed", GraphObject.Factory.create(json), new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if(response.getError() != null)
                Log.e("FRAGACTIVITY", response.getError().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "I hacked your facebook!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(req);
```

I would like to post a picture the user takes onto the public wall as well. I've tried using a Bundle instead of a JSONObject and using each of these lines:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
postPhoto.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
params.putByteArray("picture", baos.toByteArray());
params.putByteArray("source", baos.toByteArray());
```

They both give me an error like this - errorMessage: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted

Anyone know how to post a photo onto someone else's facebook wall without using deprecated functions/Objects in the facebook sdk?

Comment: what is `data`?  have you tried supplying an URL for the `picture` parameter instead?

Comment: It should be more clear now. I assume it would work if I used a URL. But I need to use a image stored locally on the phone (postPhoto).

Answer (score 2):

This is my code to upload a photo stored locally on the phone:

```
        Request request6 = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                session,
                ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.picture)).getBitmap(), callback6);
        RequestAsyncTask task6 = new RequestAsyncTask(request6);
        task6.execute();
```

This is to upload on your own wall.  Reason why there is no option to choose another recipient is due to the breaking changes in February that will disable posting to other people's wall.

[See my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829086/oauthexception-when-trying-to-post-to-friends-wall/13830728#13830728).

EDIT:

> what is the best way to upload a photo that will show up on a place's wall with a photo and message?

Can you try this and see if this works?

```
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putParcelable("picture", YOUR_BITMAP_HERE);
    parameters.putString("message", "my message for the page");

    return new Request(session, "PowerCardSoftware/feed", parameters, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```

> Can I add a message using newUploadPhotoRequest()?

No, to add a message with your photo, you won't be using `newUploadPhotoRequest`.  If you dig into the source, its just a wrapper of a `Request`, so do the same as the method, but add an additional parameter, `message`, with the message you want, and execute it.  I haven't personally verified it but it *should* work.  Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: If there is no convenient way to post a picture from local storage on a phone to a place's wall, what is the best way to upload a photo that will show up on a place's wall with a photo and message? Can I add a message using newUploadPhotoRequest()?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution.
I referenced [Jesse Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931354/jesse-chen)'s answer and made some modifications.

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "demo.jpg");
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putParcelable("source", image);
parameters.putString("message", "my message for the page");
Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/photos", parameters, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        showPublishResult(mainActivity.getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
    }
});
request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check facebookSDK project /tests folders and search keywords newPostRequest.
the sample code is as below

```
GraphObject statusUpdate = GraphObject.Factory.create();
                String message = "message";
                statusUpdate.setProperty("message", message);
                statusUpdate.setProperty("link", "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129546/android-post-picture-to-facebook-public-page-wall#");
            Request request = Request.newPostRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", statusUpdate, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                }
            });
            request.executeAsync();
```