# how to post image on facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook, image, post

I have in integer array in which I have images from drawable folder. Now I want to share image from that integer array to facebook wall.I tried the code below

```
    Uri imageuri  = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + "package name/" + mBitmapIds[int_image_position]);
    String filePath = imageuri.getEncodedPath();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("picture", filePath);
    facebookConnector.getFacebook().request("me/feed", bundle, "POST");
```

where mBitmapIds is int array but it is not posting the image on wall. can anybody tell me how can I do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14129957/2219600)... it may help..

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`AsyncFacebookRunner`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner.java).

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "picture caption");
bundle.putByteArray("picture", ImageBytes);
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new SampleUploadListener());
```

Kindly refer [Android post picture to Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168145/android-post-picture-to-facebook-wall) too.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Can we mention the size of the picture to be appear in the thumnail of the post