# Post to Friends wall on Facebook failed with Social Framework in iOS 6

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-wall, social-framework

I am trying to POST a invitation to iOS app **on my facebook friends wall** using Social framework in iOS 6+. But it gives me following error

```
error =     {
        code = 200;
        message = "(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
```

I know this is due to Facebook disable this functionality as mentioned on [Facebook blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/) & [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829086/oauthexception-when-trying-to-post-to-friends-wall)

On stackoverlow's page , it is written that use feed dialog. But I can't see any option to use feed dialog in Social framework.

What is the alternative to POST on friends wall using Social Framewrok in iOS 6 ?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi Kitty. I am end up by sending invitation to facebook friends messages using his facebook username (username@facebook.com) through email

Comment: What about usernames with spaces in them, like most FBers have?

Comment: @ user1639164 When you fetch friends from Facebook , you will get json response which contains "username" key which is different from actual name (first name & last name). You have to use this "username" to send an email. Hope this clears your doubt

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post on a friend's Timeline after the February 2013 migration takes effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190877/how-to-post-on-a-friends-timeline-after-the-february-2013-migration-takes-effec)