# Post to friend's wall Facebook iOS SDK 3.1

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

According to Facebook Developer Roadmap (https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/), they are saying that we won't be able to post to a Friend Wall except using the Feed Dialog, but feed dialog is deprecated on iOS SDK 3.1

Which is the better way to go in my case? I need a User to select from his friend list, and then post a link to their wall.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use feed dialog.  I think FB is going to have to keep this around.   My apps are using them fine right now.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/

```
- (IBAction)publishButtonAction:(id)sender {
    // Put together the dialog parameters
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
                                   @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                                   @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
                                   @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
                                   nil];

    // Invoke the dialog
    [self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

    // (here's another typical example of how to call that...)
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:
            YourFBSessionClass.activeSession
            parameters: params
            handler: nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my question [Post to Friends wall on Facebook failed with Social Framework in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332314/post-to-friends-wall-on-facebook-failed-with-social-framework-in-ios-6#comment20418219_14332314)

I end up by sending invitation to facebook friends messages using his facebook username (username@facebook.com) through email