# Facebook send dialog in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, inbox

I have an iOs app in which I tell the user to share a link with the friends he wants. I want to offer him the possibility to **open a new inbox from within the app** and if possible with pre-filled content. But no pre-filled recipient. And I want it to be available to all users (not only those with facebook connect).

Basically I want to **replicate the following send dialog for web in the app**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Which means it will open the facebook app and not the browser to show the new inbox dialog.

From my research I found no clear solution and as it is possible from a website I would be surprised I cannot do the same with the app.

Thank you very much in advance,
Jules

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712190/post-to-friends-wall-facebook-ios-sdk-3-1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIActivityViewController`.
You first have to create a list of the things you want to share: an URL, a string, etc like this

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.link-to-share.com], @"What you want written above"];
```

Afterwards, you just have to create the `UIActivityViewController` with the things you want to share and present it modally:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can also add a completion block so that you are notified when the user is done with the sharing:

```
[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
    //do stuff
}];
```