# iOS Social Framework to post to friends wall

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

My underlying goal is to allow the user of my app to invite a facebook friend to also use the app, by either posting a story to that friend's timeline, or by sending them a private message.

My hope is to do so using the iOS Social Framework exclusively.

My immediate questions are twofold:

1. Can you use the SLComposeViewController to post to a friend's wall, or is that limited to only posting to the app user's wall?
2. If SLComposeViewController cannot be used to do that, then what is the recommended method for doing so (again, within the social framework)?

Thanks!

Comment: If this link might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332314/post-to-friends-wall-on-facebook-failed-with-social-framework-in-ios-6?rq=1

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, thanks for your response, but I do not see your answer. Did you mean to link to it?

Comment: @user1639164 you can download facebook sdk and this sdk into sample code you can use this., i hope this helpfull.,,,

Comment: you can use friendpickersample code .,, then you got friends id

Comment: next call graph api https://graph.facebook.com/friendid?access_token=accesstokan

Comment: then you got friends user name

Comment: next you see this line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665476/sending-a-private-message-to-your-friends-via-facebook-ios-sdk?lq=1

Answer (score -3):

friend invite is not possible in fecebook sdk..but u can send a message to your friend easily..

Comment: The question was using the iOS Social Framework, not the Facebook SDK.